# Is it possible to have compound targets in Selenium?

Tags: selenium

I'm trying to modify the Xero bulk invoice delete tool for Selenium. Out of the box, it simply deletes invoices in the order that the column is sorted by.

However what I want to do is to delete all invoice with a Reference that has a specific prefix AND a Date that contains 2014.

I've successfully modified the targeting from the sample provided to select the right prefix using css selectors (the row that contains "css=td.ref:contains("WEB")") below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="selenium.base" href="https://go.xero.com/" />
<title>DeleteAllAccountsReceivables</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">DeleteAllAccountsReceivables</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
    <td>getEval</td>
    <td>X=0</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>getEval</td>
    <td>Items=5000</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>while</td>
    <td>X&lt;Items</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>openAndWait</td>
    <td>/AccountsReceivable/Search.aspx?invoiceStatus=INVOICESTATUS/AUTHORISED</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>css=td.ref:contains("WEB")</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>link=Void</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>pause</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>css=button:contains('OK')</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>getEval</td>
    <td>X++</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>endWhile</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

What I really need it to do is for it to test for both the above AND this condition:

```
css=td.from + td:contains("2014")
```

If both of those are matched then proceed. So far putting it in another line of ClickAndWait doesn't work as it's already loaded the next page.

This is the first time I've used Selenium and I can't seem to find any way of creating a 'compound target'. I also tried using a 'while' but with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used the Xero bulk invoice delete tool for Selenium. But I am assuming that it is a script written in Selenium IDE

I think we can use the following notation using xpath.

```
xpath=//td[contains(text(),'from')][contains(text(),'2014')]
```

or

```
xpath=//td[contains(text(),'from') and contains(text(),'2014')]
```

**EDIT - BASED ON HTML SOURCE CODE POSTED**

You can use the following xpath. This one will find the `tr` that contains `td` with text containing 'LDE' and another `td` with text containing '2014'

```
xpath=//tr[//td[@class='ref'][contains(text(),'LDE')]][//td[@class='from']/following-sibling::td[1][contains(text(),'2014')]]
```

If you are looking to get the check box against the required row, use the following xpath:

```
xpath=//tr[//td[@class='ref'][contains(text(),'LDE')]][//td[@class='from']/following-sibling::td[1][contains(text(),'2014')]]//input
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't that just match the second condition?

Edit to add: Yes, it's written for the Selenium IDE.

Comment: can you post the relevent HTML for atleast one row? Is the HTML like `<tr><td>text with prefix</td><td>text with date</td></tr>`

Comment: I've pasted an entire row here: http://pastebin.com/gpJE3euT

      In my example above the '+' symbol indicates an adjacent sibling selector, so the first condition to match is any td.ref that contains the text 'LDE', the second condition to match is the first td AFTER td.from that contains the text '2014'.

Comment: @KelseyBrookes, Please find the updated answer above.